# How to get a const value in a Model

Tags: php, fuelphp

```
class Model_Item_Review extends \Orm\Model_Soft
{

    const UNCHECK = 0;
    const PUBLISH = 1;

    public static function validate()
    {
    $val = Validation::forge('model.item_review_create');
    return $val;
    }


 }
```

I usually use the function like this \Model_Item_Review::validate();

I wonder how to get the const value of the in the Model like this way.
eg.`\Model_Item_Review::UNCHECK;`

it seems not work

Comment: `\Model_Item_Review::UNCHECK` It works.

Comment: Within the methods of `Model_Item_Review` itself you would use `self::<const-name>`; outside of it you would reference the canonical class name.